# Can we add links providing guidance to the review queues (the close queue in particular)?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close

Can we add links providing guidance when voting in the review queues? Particularly the close queue?

**Why I'm asking**:
In performing a few close votes I came across a question which on the surface looked like a very poor question. There was no code provided, although the solution was a small script. My instinct was to select "close" but before closing I always visit the actual question (unless the question is pure nonsense).

I saw that there were already 4 close votes, one more and that would be it. I looked at an answer someone had provided; as the question was not in a domain for which I'm familiar, in reading the answer the content of the question became clear as the answerer was clearly expert enough to have intuition regarding what the novice was asking. So I edited the question to provide a touch more formatting, which was all that was required to make it clear to the larger audience.

While looking at the question I thought (*this is still not my question btw*): What makes a good question? Should questions be considered in isolation of answers? If not, then why only show the question, what is the design decision for this? What does it mean to close a question, will it reduce viewer-ship or access to the answer? What does it mean to the good answers that have been supplied, after being closed can the OP select a correct answer?

I can find answers to the above questions if I search and I reread https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions (which did answer a couple of those). But I think having some guidance, a wiki page that covers some of these, perhaps a wiki meta page that that is directly linked which is kept up with the current state of: `When should I vote to close?`

This isn't to say I expect this to be mandatory reading, but there are cases where I would like to see some place where opinion on these matters has been aggregated and I would like it provided as a link above the relevant queues such that I can resolve my doubts in a timely way.

From "Why I'm asking" to here, I hope provides insight into someone who is in the top 4% on SO (for which many people on meta are *far* above), and that after all this time if I'm not always certain about when a question should be closed perhaps, others could use some help as well or perhaps; even worse, some are even certain *they don't need help but most certainly do*!

---

Further, I think some effort at codification may be helpful in shifting SO culture. Many people will use these tools without awareness of trends in meta, without a means of digesting these trends and making them readily accessible, the good opinions here may not reach the masses. I also think the review queues are a significant source of User Experience; particularly, as experienced by new users. So a means of guidance can also be used by the powers that be to create the *correct* experience.

Comment: Although not completely answering the question: 1) Questions should be judged in isolation of answers. Either it is a good question or not, it shouldn't matter if some user was able to decipher the content and provide an answer. 2) Considerations like "the question already has 4 close votes, when I vote to close that will be it" shouldn't influence your decision at all. 3) Don't act any different when close-voting in a review queue than when stumbling over them outside of a queue. So what you actually might be looking for is not a guide for the review queue but for close-voting in general.

Comment: My only question is the first line. The rest is just what needs to have consideration, the point about the four close votes was that, in looking at only the review queue and not visiting the question would result in a closed question (and I think wrongly so), we can visit the question and for a valid opinion... anyways I digress the point is I would like better guidance, and the rest is just some of what your typical silly user is thinking.

Comment: @BDL also I agree with all you've said. Also yes, it is the close queue that I had the issue with, and I think it also has the most impact if people vote incorrectly.

Comment: I'm a firm believer in having documentation for every queue. _[Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](/a/295674/5764553)_ is a great example and is now helpfully linked to from the Triage queue. However, it should be noted that since the Close Votes queue (and close votes in general) is not Stack Overflow specific, any FAQ would probably be better on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/318307) instead.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I think that was quite clear, I've never reviewed the Triage queue... it is certainly nice that it is there. I feel that what should and shouldn't be closed is pretty important to the community. I have a feeling some communities are more tolerant than others, so for that reason I think SO needs its own page. Some SE sites handle quite subjective content, and are happy to have speculation, SO is not and clearly has its own rules. I think preaching tolerance and how to help new users, could be beneficial on such a page but the "tolerance" I envision, is still pretty draconian...

Comment: but I think such a page would be a good place to clear up that distinction between draconian and _too draconian_.

Comment: @Quaternion _"some communities are more tolerant than others"_ - Quite true; I forgot about that. However that does make things a little awkward for making a FAQ here. Different tags on SO practically have their own communities (with different standards for closing), not to mention a few groups on Meta that have trouble agreeing as well. You could try writing your own FAQ ([see the end of this](/q/251225/5764553)) and see if it works out.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I've made note of the link. I'll make a guide for the close queue. Any difficulties in doing so, are probably directly proportional to its need. So I'll let that motivate me.